# MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications, mpmovieplayer

MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification is working fine in IOS 4.0 (>=3.2). But leaves a white screen when loaded in IOS 3.1.3 (<3.2).

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the iOS Class Reference, that notification is available in iOS 3.2 or later.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953